# Subscript text in pdf C#

Tags: c#, string

How do I insert a subscript character in a string in C#?

I have problems appending a superscript "2" in the same string using `char.ConvertFromUtf32(178);`, but I struggle with finding a similar solution for the subscripted text. Actually, I'm struggling with finding any solution at all to this rather embarrassing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain text doesn't have formatting, like superscript, subscript, bold, italic and/or colors.
You need to use some "rich text" format.
The type of "rich text" depends on where you want to use it. Examples: HTML, RTF.

For PDF you need to look into the formatting options provided by your PDF creation library.

Comment: There are some options for doing this in the PDF-library (Aspose), but I don't find it very intuitive to do it that way. It entails instatiating a series of text object and appending the subscript part in the relevant place. The superscript solution worked like a charm, so I had hoped there was a similar solution to this problem, but it doesn't seem like that is an option. Thank you Hans.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF creation library I'm using did not offer much.
One work around I could figure out was to pick equalent ascii values from charecter map and append it to the existing string.